# How to load Listview items into image object and update it in OnTimer event in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm a noob in Delphi V7. I'm creating a SlideShow, i need the images loaded in a ListView be sent to a Picture object using the OnTimer event of the Timer object. See the code I'm using:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
if open1.execute then
begin
 for i := 0 to Open1.Files.Count - 1 do

   //     ShowMessage(Open1.Files[i]);   // processa os arquivos aqui
with add.Items.Add do
  begin
    Caption:=ExtractFileName(Open1.Files[i]);
    SubItems.Add( Open1.Files[i]);
    SubItems.Add(ExtractfileExt(Open1.files[i]));

  end;
```

The above section add various images of a opendialog object into a ListView.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
timer1.enabled:=true;
//image1.Picture.loadfromfile(add.Items.Item[0].Caption);//Assign(add.Items.Item[0].Caption);
end;
```

This active the timer.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;

begin

for i := 0 to add.items.count -1 do
begin
image1.Picture.loadfromfile(add.Items.Item[i].Caption  );//Assign(add.Items.Item[0].Caption);
  end;
end;
```

But i'm need help in the last code. This not working.

I want the images to be loaded one by one in the image1 object whenever the timer times out, giving a slideshow effect, but the code that I typed in the OnTimer event, carries only one image.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please be precise so that we do not have to guess.

Comment: Sorry, i want the images to be loaded one by one in the image1 object whenever the timer times out, giving a slideshow effect, but the code that I typed in the OnTimer event, carries only one image.

Comment: That `for` loop loads all the images in turn everytime the timer ticks. You'll need to have a global variable, e.g. a private field in your form to store the current index of the list view item and every time the timer ticks, you'll load the image and increase its value (or reset to the first one if it was the last item).

Comment: You might be looking for a code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/z5AfAMFJ) (though I'm not a fan of this concept).

Comment: It would be simpler if the Delphi owned a TImage component with options ImageList and ImageIndex, so I just need to use:

`Procedure TImer1Timer [...]

Image1.Picture: Image1.Picture + = 1;`

Does anyone have any idea of a component as well? Or how to create a TImage component that inherits the characteristics of an ImageList and ImageIndex Imagelist?

Comment: @TLama Why do you put answers in pastebins and then link to them in comments? Why don't you answer the question?

Comment: Look into [`NGLN's repository`](https://svn.apada.nl/svn/NLDelphi-opensource/ngln/). If I remember that right, he's made some sort of slideshow image component. I bet he'll be right here to tell you more.

Comment: @TLama I don't understand that comment. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @TLama That's just part of SO. And anyway, it's a little rich for you to state that. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286704/pausing-an-introduction-screen/16286899#16286899

Comment: @TLama Oh, I'm disappointed to hear you talking of revenge. That's not very savoury.

Comment: @TLama I think that's a shame. I've always really enjoyed your answers. I like reading them, and I learn a lot.

Comment: @TLama OK, no worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your timer you load every single image, overwriting each image with the next until the loop terminates. At which point image `Count-1` remains.

You need to keep track of some state that persists between each execution of the timer event. Declare a field in `TForm1` named `FLatestImageIndex` of type `Integer`. Then make your timer like so:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLatestImageIndex := FLatestImageIndex mod add.Items.Count;//wrap around
  image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(add.Items.Item[FLatestImageIndex].Caption);
  inc(FLatestImageIndex);
end;
```

If you have code that stops and starts the slideshow then you'll likely want to re-initialise `FLatestImageIndex` each time you start.

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan and TLama, i will test both solutions and post the result here. Thanks!